# Tranferring images from Spring Rest web service to client and vice versa

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

In my Spring Rest web service ,I want to transfer image from web service to client (Windows Form) and vice versa. What I'am doing now is,I convert the image to Base64 string and transferring.I know its not a good method.Please suggest me the best method for doing the same.

Comment: Please see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656085/how-to-send-an-image-from-web-service-in-spring

Comment: Thanks.I will try this method.But how to get image from client side?