# http streaming inbound channel in spring integration

Tags: streaming, spring-integration

I need an http inbound streaming channel similar to the ftp-streaming adapter channel (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-streaming) but I could not find one, is it supported in SI? In case not, is it possible a workaround?

I need to receive a soap message from an http streaming channel, transform a message using SAX and then send it to a http outbound stream channel

Comment: Would you mind elaborating more what is that "HTTP Streaming"? Thanks

Comment: something like having an InputStream as payload so I can sign or encrypt the payload using the streaming capabilities of wss4j https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/streaming.html. Here's an old post asking for the same I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096563/spring-integration-returning-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you talk about SOAP and SAX, you don't need to worry about `InputStream`. There is `SourceHttpMessageConverter` which is present in the `int-http:inbound-channel-adapter`. It can produce `SAXSource` for you.

What only you need is:

```
request-payload-type="javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource"
```

configuration option.