# How to return the Image as ResponseEntity<byte[]> and display same using Thyme leaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using thyme leaf for one my project, I have problem in generating a QRCode and display the same in browser and I am using spring mvc framework.

1. I will send the product id to API layer, that has to create QR code for that id. That should not save in anywhere and return as response as byte[]
2. using thyme leaf framework have to display the image in browser

Please help on the same.

Regards
Mohan

Comment: One request means one response. You're trying to do two things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just send a HTTP request to your controller.

In your Thymeleaf template, set the source of your image to the url of your Spring MVC controller:

```
<img th:src="@{/controller/qr/${id}}" />
```

Provide a method in your controller that returns the image as `ResponseEntity`:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/qr/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getQRImage(@PathVariable final String id) {
    byte[] bytes = ...; // Generate the image based on the id

    // Set headers
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]> (bytes, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

More answers can be found in this question: [Spring MVC: How to return image in @ResponseBody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690228/spring-mvc-how-to-return-image-in-responsebody)

Comment: Retrieve the byte[] content and convert it into `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byte[] content)` then set it as a Context Variable and then process the templateEngine to the pass the variable as `<img th:src="@{'data:image/png;base64,' + ${Base64String object's Context key} }" />` in Thymeleaf