# Please help me out from this i am new to spring MVC :how to display images from Db using Spring mvc

Tags: spring

my problem is how to render the images in jsp from db,
image upload was sucessfull but i am getting problem in rendering the images from DB i am using MySql Db

my Model class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="photo")
public class Photo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private MultipartFile file;
    private byte[] imageContent;
    private int imageId;


    @Column(name="forId")
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name="photoName")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Transient
    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Lob
    @Column(name="image",columnDefinition="blob")
    public byte[] getImageContent() {
        return imageContent;
    }
    public void setImageContent(byte[] imageContent) {
        this.imageContent = imageContent;
    }
}
```

LIst of Images jsp page (in this page only i have to display images from DB)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:out value="${message }"></c:out>
<img src='<c:url  value="/image?imageId=${imageId }"/>'/>
</body>
</html>
```

controller is

```
@Controller                                                                                                                       
public class HomeController {                                                                                                     
    @Autowired                                                                                                                    
    private PhotoService photoService;                                                                                            

    public PhotoService getPhotoService() {                                                                                       
        return photoService;                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                             

    public void setPhotoService(PhotoService photoService) {                                                                      
        this.photoService = photoService;                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                             

    public static Logger getLogger() {                                                                                            
        return logger;                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                             

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);                                           

    /**                                                                                                                           
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.                                                              
     */                                                                                                                           
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)                                                                      
    public String home(@ModelAttribute("photo")Photo photo,Locale locale, Model model) {                                          

        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);                                                            
        return "home";                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                             

    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadPhoto",method=RequestMethod.POST)                                                               
    public String uploadImage(@ModelAttribute("photo")Photo  photo,@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile multipartFile,Model model) {
            byte[] imageContent=null;                                                                                             
                try {                                                                                                             
                    imageContent =photo.getFile().getBytes();                                                                     
                    }                                                                                                             
                    catch(Exception e) {                                                                                          
                        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                      
                    }                                                                                                             
                System.out.println(imageContent);                                                                                 
            photo.setImageContent(imageContent);                                                                                  
            this.photoService.storePhoto(photo);                                                                                  
            model.addAttribute("message", photo.getName());                                                                       
            model.addAttribute("imageId", photo.getImageId());                                                                    
      return"listOfImages";                                                                                                       
     }                                                                                                                            

    @RequestMapping("/image")                                                                                                     
    public String getImages(@RequestParam("imageId")int imageId,HttpServletResponse response,Model model) {                       
        byte[] image=null;                                                                                                        
        try {                                                                                                                     
            image=this.photoService.getPhotoByPhotoId(imageId).getImageContent();                                                 
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");                                                                                 
            response.getOutputStream().write(image);                                                                              
            response.getOutputStream().flush();                                                                                   
            response.getOutputStream().close();                                                                                   
        } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                                 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                                                                    
            e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                         
        return"listOfImages";                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                             
}
```

Dao implementation for this is

```
@Repository("photoDao")
public class PhotoDaoImpl implements PhotoDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory SessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return SessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        SessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to store the photo attributes to DB
     */
    @Override
    public Photo storePhoto(Photo photo) {
            Session session =this.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.save(photo);
       return photo;
    }
    @Override
    public Photo getPhotoByPhotoId(int id) {
        Session session =this.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Photo photo =null;
        photo = (Photo)session.get(Photo.class, id);
        return photo;
    }


}
```

Service implementation for this is

```
@Service("photoSertvice")
public class PhotoServiceImpl implements PhotoService {
    @Autowired
    private PhotoDao photoDao;

    public PhotoDao getPhotoDao() {
        return photoDao;
    }

    public void setPhotoDao(PhotoDao photoDao) {
        this.photoDao = photoDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Photo storePhoto(Photo photo) {
            return this.photoDao.storePhoto(photo);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Photo getPhotoByPhotoId(int id) {
        return this.photoDao.getPhotoByPhotoId(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either @ResponseBody or ResponseEntity to return the byte array from the 'getImages()' methid. 
See this: [Spring MVC: How to return image in @ResponseBody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690228/spring-mvc-how-to-return-image-in-responsebody) 
For example:

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImages(@RequestParam("imageId") int imageId) {
    byte[] image = ...;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(image, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

If this results in an error of kind "no converter for byte array" you'll have to register the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter (see the above link for details). But normally it should be registered by default.

Comment: @Alexandar please give me ur mail id so that i can send  code of mine so that you can correct it