# proper way to use getBean() to create Beans dynamically

Tags: spring, javabeans

Setup : 
 - have a Several Configuration Class containing Bean definitions for my beans
 - I will fetched a List of String from a database containing all the bean names and their corresponding Configuration class I want to instantiate dynamically

currently I will do a loop on the list and then call a method passing the beanName and the Configuration Class containing the bean definition:

```
private Object getBean(String beanName, Class configurationClass) {
    Object bean = null;
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            configurationClass);
    bean = context.getBean(beanName);
    return bean;
}
```

I would then use the returned object and used Reflections to invoke specific Methods based on a list I fetched from a database.

Question : Is there a proper way to do this ? because for every bean I want to create  , I think performance will be affected.

Comment: Could you explain a little what is the use case for this?

Comment: trying to create a program where we can dynamically add algorithms to business objects , lets say before a record can be created , we can define 10 algorithms that would run before the record will be actually created, those 10 algorithms can be changed anytime on the application as per needed , and the algorithms can also be re used by other business objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in spring 4.1

I found the below example in this post - [Spring MVC: How to return image in @ResponseBody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690228/spring-mvc-how-to-return-image-in-responsebody)

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadUserAvatarImage(@PathVariable Long userId) {
GridFSDBFile gridFsFile = fileService.findUserAccountAvatarById(userId);

return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentLength(gridFsFile.getLength())
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(gridFsFile.getContentType()))
        .body(new InputStreamResource(gridFsFile.getInputStream()));

}
```