# How to show image from byte array to image tag

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have an image stored in MYSQL as BLOB. Now I have retrieved it as byte array, but i can not figure out how to show it in image tag.I searched for available answers but none of them helped me so far. And when I call my service from postman the image comes up red. Below is the code

Service layer

```
 @GET
 @Path("/downloadLogo/{merchantId}")
 @Produces({"image/png", "image/jpeg"})
 public Response downloadLogo(@PathParam("merchantId") Long merchantId) {
  MerchantImage merchantImage=this.merchantService.findMerchantImage(merchantId);
     ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(merchantImage.getMerchantLogo()); //getMerchantLogo() gets the byte array
     responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+merchantImage.getLogoName()+"\"");
     return responseBuilder.build();
 }
```

Ajax request

```
function downloadData(data,serviceUrl, element){
  if(!authorizedimage()){return false;};
     $.support.cors = true;
   $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: serviceUrl,
             crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "binary",
    headers:{'Content-Type':'image/png','X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'},
             processData: false,
             success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {alert("success");
    if (typeof fnSuccess !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(fnSuccess)) {
     fnSuccess('image', data, element);
    }
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, status) {

       $('#image_view').append('<img id="uploaded_image" src="data:image/png;base64,'+[jqXHR.responseText]+'">');   
                console.log(jqXHR, typeof jqXHR.responseText);
    if(jqXHR.statusText == "Unauthorized"){
     logout();
    }
             }
          });
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690228/spring-mvc-how-to-return-image-in-responsebody

Comment: Bad, bad, ugly idea to store image as a blob!!! Either go with base64 strings if you're lazy enough to make a normal file uploader.

Comment: @user3560988  Thank you for your suggestion .. i realized its a bad way and made a normal file uploader , which works just fine