# How to return image in Spring REST to browser

Tags: spring, image, rest, controller, spring-rest

I need to return image in my Spring controller. 
I try answer in this [Spring MVC: How to return image in @ResponseBody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690228/spring-mvc-how-to-return-image-in-responsebody) but it's not working

my code is like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "cabang/photo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPhoto() throws IOException {

     File imgPath = new File("D:\\test.jpg");

    byte[] image = Files.readAllBytes(imgPath.toPath());
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    headers.setContentLength(image.length);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

but when I access it in browser, it doesn't show anything (just no picture icon). But if I read the image byte array, it is not empty.
Do I miss anything in my code?

Comment: Open your browser's network console and check what the response contains. Post that here.

Comment: oh, looks like the type is still 'document'. But I set it in headers, so it should return image. Maybe I set it the wrong way?

Comment: What you currently have should properly set the content-type header. Check that your handler method is properly invoked. Note that `@ResponseBody` is unnecessary since your return type is `ResponseEntity`. Remove it.

Comment: hmm.. in the response header, content-type already image/jpeg, in response, it is not empty.. like "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQE..." but I don't know why the browser doesn't not show it. I can check the byte array, so I think the method is invoked

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok. Make sure you added `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` to your application's list of http message converters.

Java Config :

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
    converters.add(byteConverter);
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```