# jacksonMessageConverter corrupt mp3 file as octet encode response

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a spring MVC config with the following:

```
       public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter() {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

            messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
            return messageConverter;
        }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        }
      }
```

The previous method used to ignore all lazy relation without adding JsonIgnore in model
The problem is I have a route to steam mp3 file as an octet response as following

```
@GetMapping(value = "/audio/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> streamMp3FileToAdmin(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    CorporateCampaign camp = corporateCampaignService.findById(id);
    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(Utilities.getFileAsBytes(camp.getVoiceUrl()),httpHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If I remove jackson message converter the steaming works fine but when I add jackson message converter the stream doesn't work any more

I read this question [Spring MVC: How to return image in @ResponseBody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690228/spring-mvc-how-to-return-image-in-responsebody)

and a lot but I didn't find a solution yet

Comment: Looks like you miss `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` part in the request mapping

Comment: @StanislavL That's true thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` to the `@GetMapping(value = "/audio/{id}")` to specify produced result content type and let browser recognize it properly.